# Handle all routes with a prefix in separate js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have multiple routes in my express application for different prefix. Each prefix's routes are defined in separate files.

```
const routes = require('./server/routes');
app.use('/api', routes.apirouter);
app.use('/', routes.webrouter);
```

where './server/routes.js' is:

```
module.exports.apirouter = require('./api');
module.exports.webrouter = require('./webroutes');
```

Hence currently, I am handling and defined all routes with /api prefix in 'api.js' and all other routes are defined in 'webroutes.js'

Now similarly I need to define all the routes with prefix 'fetch-' to a separate js file 'fetch.js', hence http://localhost/fetch-one and http://localhost/fetch-two need to be defined in **fetch.js**

However the following code is not working for /fetch-one:

```
const routes = require('./server/routes');
app.use('/api', routes.apirouter);
app.use('/', routes.webrouter);
app.use('/fetch-*', routes.fetchrouter);
```

routes.js:

```
module.exports.apirouter = require('./api');
module.exports.webrouter = require('./webroutes');
module.exports.fetchrouter = require('./fetch');
```

fetch.js:
Route defined for /fetch-one and /fetch-two separately in fetch.js

```
var fetchRouter = require('express').Router();
fetchRouter.get('/fetch-one', function(req, res, next) {
    // localhost/fetch-one not passed control here
});
fetchRouter.get('/fetch-two', function(req, res, next) {
    // localhost/fetch-two not passed control here
})
module.exports = fetchRouter;
```

Comment: `app.use('/', routes.webrouter);` - try move this after `app.use('/fetch-*', routes.fetchrouter);`

Comment: maybe `app.use('/', routes.webrouter);` doesn't call `next` and request-response cycle gets terminated before reaching `app.use('/fetch-*', routes.fetchrouter);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that once you've done this:

```
 app.use('/fetch-*', routes.fetchrouter);
```

Then, the `/fetch-*` part of the path has been removed from the routing for the fetchrouter.  So, when you then do:

```
fetchRouter.get('/fetch-one', ...)
```

That won't match because `/fetch-one` has already been removed from the routing path.  The URL would have to have been `/fetch-xxx/fetch-one` for that to match.

The simplest design would be to change your paths so that the URLs are `/fetch/one` and `/fetch/two` which is much more in line with how Express routers work.  Then you'd go with:

```
 app.use('/fetch', routes.fetchrouter);
```

And, have routes in that router for

```
 app.get('/one, ...)
 app.get('/two, ...)
```

That's the URL design that lines up the cleanest with the way Express routers work the simplest.

---

If you're going to stay with the `/fetch-one` URL design, then another idea would be to let the `fetchRouter` look at all top level URLs:

```
 app.use('/', fetchRouter);
```

And, then have it only have routes for the top level routes you want it to look at.  Express will then continue look for other routes that match if it doesn't handle things:

```
 app.get('/fetch-one', ...);
 app.get('/fetch-two', ...);
```

You need to make sure there are no greedy top level routers that take all requests and make sure that this router only takes the request that it needs so that other top level routes get a chance to get matched.

---

If you really want to stay with the `/fetch-*` design for the router, then you can do a bit of your own routing and URL comparison:

```
 app.use('/fetch-*', routes.fetchrouter);
```

Then, in the fetchrouter:

```
 app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
     switch(req.baseUrl) {
         case "/fetch-one":
             // process /fetch-one here
             break;
         case "/fetch-two":
             // process /fetch-two here
             break;
         default:
             next();
     }
 });
```

---

I thought of one other option that uses the Express parameters where you would just use a handler function for the fetch routes instead of a router:

```
 app.use('/fetch-:id', routes.fetchHandler);
```

Then, in the fetchHandler:

```
 function fetchHandler(req, res, next) {
     switch(req.params.id) {
         case "one":
             // process /fetch-one here
             break;
         case "two":
             // process /fetch-two here
             break;
         default:
             next();
     }
 });
```

---

Instead of a big switch, you can make it table driven too which is probably cleaner if you have a lot of routes:

```
 app.use('/fetch-:id', routes.fetchHandler);
```

Then, fetchHandler would be an exported function:

```
 const routeTable = {
     one: routeOne,
     two: routeTwo,
     three: routeThree,
     ....
 };

 function fetchHandler(req, res, next) {
     let fn = routeTable[req.params.id];
     if (fn) {
         fn(req, res, next);
     } else {
         next();
     }
 });

 function routeOne(req, res, next) {
     ...
 }

 function routeTwo(req, res, next) {
     ...
 }

 function routeThree(req, res, next) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with the last one. But that'll be messy with so many fetch-* routes.

Comment: @AdamsHales - See the additional options I added, including a table-driven option that might work well if you have a lot of routes.